# Proper random effects structure in simple design

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I am aware that many questions have been asked about mixed models before, and the distinction between random effects and fixed effects. I sincerely hope that this is not a duplicate.

I can appreciate the distinction between random and fixed factors, and am interpreting them most in line with Gelman, in that fixed effects are not partially pooled, and random effects are. Thus the former do not vary as a function of the individual, but the latter do.

I also keep in mind Bolker's quote from one of this book chapters:

"The traditional view of random effects is as a way to do correct statistical tests when some observations are correlated."

So here is the specific situation. Consider individuals who are exposed to both a control condition, and then a treatment condition, and then their reaction time is measured. However, each individual is tested twice within each condition (so 2 trials per condition, therefore 4 measurements per person).

Here is a data-generating model as an example of the described design:

```
#### four measurements per person ####
set.seed(1234)
x1.1 <- rnorm(200,0,1)
x1.2 <- .6*x1.1 + rnorm(200,0,.2)
x2.1 <- 1 + .3*x1.1 + rnorm(200,0,.75)
x2.2 <- 1 + .6*x2.1 + .3*x2.1 + rnorm(200,0,.1)

df4b <- data.frame(x1.1,x2.1,x1.2,x2.2)
#restructure data
x <- c(x1.1,x1.2,x2.1,x2.2)
id <- rep(1:200,times=4)
t <- rep(1:2,each=400)
trial <- rep(1:2,each=200,times=2)
df4blong <- data.frame(id,x,t=factor(t),trial=factor(trial))
```

It seems there are a variety of mixed models that could be fit.

1)

```
lmer(x~1+t+((1+t)|id),data=df4blong)
```

A model in which the intercept is random and the effect of treatment is random. In essence, each individual get's their own (partially pooled) intercept and treatment effect. This seems to be attractive because we now see the magnitude of the treatment effect, but we also see how it differs for each individual. The degrees of freedom for the intercept and random slope (treatment effect) are 199 each, which appears to make sense, because there were 200 individuals. 
But in this model, the repeated measurement of each individual within each condition (the trials) never shows up, and I wonder whether the classic definition of the mixed effects model (a correct statistical test when observations are correlated) is properly used here. In other words, am I correctly modeling the dependency structure in the data?

2)

```
lmer(x~1+t+(1|trial) + (1|id:trial),data=df4blong)
```

So the alternative is to say, there are trials, and there are individuals. And the individuals are nested within trials, which are nested in the conditions. In this alternative model, the intercept varies as a function of trial, and also as a function of id nested within trial. I can't add any random effect for the treatment, as I am already exhausting possible random effects here. Adding anything else results in non-convergence. Here it seems I am (maybe) correctly defining the dependency structure, but the degrees of freedom for the treatment effects are now 399, which doesn't seem right, since I only have 200 unique individuals in each condition, and not 400 (even though I have 400 datapoints in each condition, but each subject is measured twice).

Is my thinking about these random effects off? I personally gravitate towards the first model, but I am not entirely sure that this is correct.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that trials #1 in condition A and #1 in condition B could be more similar to each other (for any given subject) than trials #2? If not, then an effect of `trial` does not make sense.

Comment: No, there is no specific reason to think that. What I am struggling with however is this notion that dependencies like this are plausible or not plausible (the one that you pointed out being not plausible) and the notion that the design itself imposes dependencies that need to be modeled for correct inference (e.g., the Bolker quote in my post).

Comment: I am not sure model 2) makes sense, for the reason indicated by @amoeba and because I don't think trial should be modeled as random effect. If you repeated the same experiment you'd end up with 200 new levels of `id` but the same 2 levels of `trial` (#1 and #2), suggesting that trial should be rather considered as fixed effect (an experimental manipulation). Model 1) instead takes into account that observations are grouped according to `id`, meaning that measurements made on the same individual should be more similar (correlated) to each other than measurements made on different individuals

Comment: Felix, I think you are overcomplicating it. "Dependency" arises when there is some factor that is not included in the model even though it should be included. If you don't include `id` as a factor then you have unaccounted dependency and that's bad. For that reason you should have either fixed or random effect of `id` (random makes more sense). But repeated measurements do not introduce any additional dependency. HOWEVER, looking at how you generate your data, your trials #1 and #2 are actually not independent (given subject and condition).  This does not really fit to your own description.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for discussing this with me. I agree with both of you that the first model makes more sense. It was my intuition as well. I guess my issue was that I couldn't more formally argue why this is the case. And regarding the data-generating model: it was not thoroughly thought through. Just a quick attempt for some data with repeated measures, that as you pointed out does not perfectly match my description.